# Get http://localhost:8000/Stack/script.js net:: Err_Aborted 404 / Django project

Tags: javascript, django, get, static

So I am attempting to build a simple to-do app, but when trying to work with some javascript to make the home page, I get the error detailed above (Get http://localhost:8000/Stack/script.js net:: Err_Aborted 404 ). I don't understand what I am doing wrong because this is my first time trying to work with javascript in my Django projects. Below is my code

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "Stack.apps.StackConfig",
    "crispy_forms",
]

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
```

base.py

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Stack/styles.css' %}">

    <title>Stack | Home </title>
</head>
<body>
{%block content%}
{%endblock content%}

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="Stack/script.js" ></script>
```

[image: My directories]

If I need to upload any more code to help solve this problem, please let me know. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 error means your script could not be found. I would suggest using the {% static ... %} template tag as follows:

```
<script src="{% static 'Stack/script.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: You are using this correctly above to load your stylesheet, which is in the same folder :-)